# How do I ensure ZK Popup appears below the appropriate component, scrolling if needed?

Tags: java, zk

I am implementing an auto-complete popup for a text field, so I need the popup to always appear below the text field.  The standard way to do this in ZK is:

```
    popup.open( field, "after_start" );
```

This would be fine, except my text box is part of a grid control.  When the user is entering data on a row near the bottom of the screen, such that there isn't enough room to display the popup below the field, ZK adjusts the popup position to keep it fully visible, thus obscuring the textbox control.

My desktop by design has sufficient room to display the popup below the field; I just need to ensure the client gets scrolled so the popup stays below the field.

I've tried using `Clients.scrollIntoView( popup );`, but that doesn't help because the popup is automatically in view.

Another possibility I know is to use the `"end_before"` position value to position the popup to the right of the text box, but that isn't consistent with the standard UI conventions for an auto-complete popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup position could be adjusted with the `opts` argument of the `open` method of a Popup widget (from the client side). 
See the [reference](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/zul/wgt/Popup.html#open%28zk.Widget,%20_global_.Offset,%20_global_.String,%20_global_.Map%29) for that method for more details.

Unfortunately there is no way to set this argument value from Java code and you should override the default behavior of the client (i.e. javascript) `open` method to get the result.

Overriding of widget's methods is described in [this article](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Client-side%20Reference/General%20Control/Widget%20Customization).

In your case you should set `opts.overflow` property to any value before calling original `open` method. For example:

```
<popup xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
    <attribute w:name="open">
        function (ref, offset, position, opts) {
            var _opts = opts || {}; // opts can be undefined! 
            _opts.overflow = true;
            this.$open(ref, offset, position, _opts);
        }
    </attribute>
</popup>
```

After opening this popup with the `popup.open` use `Clients.scrollIntoView` to make it visible if you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and for the documentation links.  I tweaked your solution a bit: in order to ensure that the call to `Clients.scrollIntoView` always happens after the popup is visible, I used an `onOpen` listener on the popup, and added the `sendOnOpen` option to `_opts`.